# Problem in understanding a proof in Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

[image]

This question in the reference to Number Theory (Modular Arithmetic). I need some help in understanding the proof of Proposition 6.

In the third line of the proof of Proposition 6,

> "$\dots 0\leq k,l\leq (n-1)$. Therefore $|k-l|<n;\dots$"

Can someone please explain this. How did we get "$|k-l|<n$"?

In the 5th line,

> "This means that $\{a,a+d,a+2d,\dots,a+(n-1)d\}=\{0,1,2,\dots,(n-1)\}$ modulo $n$. Further if $a+jd\equiv k \pmod{n}$ with $0\leq k<(n-1)$, then $(a+jd,n)=1$ iff $(k,n)=1.$ Hence the number of integers in $S$ which are prime to $n$ is precisely $\phi(n)$."

I do not understand the entire thing.

Why is "$\{a,a+d,a+2d,\dots,a+(n-1)d\}=\{0,1,2,\dots,(n-1)\}$ modulo $n$"?

Why is the inequality $0\leq k<(n-1)$ and not $0\leq k\leq (n-1)$?

Why is $(a+jd,n)=1$ iff $(k,n)=1$?

Please help.

Comment: First question: if you take two numbers that are between $0$ and $n-1$, how far apart can they be form each other? Less than $n$ apart, for sure. (Two numbers between $1$ and $10$ are always less than $11$ away from each other, no?)

Comment: Question 2: No two elements of the first set are congruent modulo $n$, and there’s $n$ of them, so they must correspond exactly to the possible remainders modulo $n$, namely $0$, $1,\ldots,n-1$.

Comment: Re: the rest of your second set of questions. First, I am quite certain it's a typo regarding $0 \leq k \lt (n-1)$. It should be $0 \leq k \leq (n-1)$ as you suggest. Second, as for why "$(a+jd,n)=1$ iff $(k,n)=1$", note that since $a+jd\equiv k \pmod{n}$, then $a+jd - k = mn$ for some integer $m$. Consider $(k,n) = 1$. If $d_1 = (a+jd,n)$ is not $1$, then $d_1$ also divides not only $n$, but also $k$, so $d_1 \mid (k,n)$, so this means that $d_1 = 1$. A similar argument can be made to show that $(a_jd,n) = 1$ gives that $(k,n) = 1$.

Comment: The presentation obfuscates the simple key idea: $f(n) = a+n\,$ and $\,g(n) = dn\,$ are invertible so bijections (permutations) on $\, \Bbb Z\bmod n = \{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}\,$ hence so too is their composition $\,f(g(n)) = a+dn.$ $\ \ \ $